# Why two ViewSets have identical url in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Why two different viewsets have identical url? How can I change it?

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'general-worker', GeneralWorkerViewSet)
router.register(r'full-info-worker', FullInfoWorkerViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/v1/drf-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
```

json from http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/

```
{
    "general-worker": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/full-info-worker/",
    "full-info-worker": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/full-info-worker/"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can not solve your example, we have not enough information.
I can imagine, it can help:

```
router.register(r'general-worker', GeneralWorkerViewSet, basename='generalWorker')
router.register(r'full-info-worker', FullInfoWorkerViewSet, basename='fullInfoWorker')
```

try to use `basename` parameter.
docs here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/